# Why doesn't this function loop infinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am quite new to jQuery had have developed this code for a slideshow. But seems this code wouldn't help loop infinitely. It runs once and comes to a halt. Can anyone please elaborate why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Initialization
    var slideCount = $('#slideshow').children().length;
    var currentID = 1;
    $('.slides').css('display','none');
    $('#slide' + currentID).fadeIn(1000);
    //Processing
    setInterval(function(){
        var nextID = currentID + 1;
        $('#slide' + currentID).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#slide' + nextID).fadeIn(1000);
        currentID = nextID;
        if(currentID == slideCount)
        {
            currentID = 1;
        }
    },2000);
});
```

The `HTML` layout of the slides is as follows:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="../../resources/images/image1.jpg" id="slide1" class="slides" />
        <img src="../../resources/images/image2.jpg" id="slide2" class="slides" />
        <img src="../../resources/images/image3.jpg" id="slide3" class="slides" />
        <img src="../../resources/images/image4.jpg" id="slide4" class="slides" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it does loop infinitely? It just keeps repeating `1` to `4`

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/YTNWQ/) a pure CSS slideshow in this style - may need prefixes adding to work in Chrome, though. Still, goes to show the power of CSS and the obsolete-ness of jQuery ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does loop forever. Howeve you pobably want to change

```
var nextID = currentID + 1;
// nextID becomes 5, which doesn't exists
$('#slide' + currentID).fadeOut(1000);
$('#slide' + nextID).fadeIn(1000);
currentID = nextID;
if(currentID == slideCount)
{
    currentID = 1;
}
```

into

```
var nextID = currentID + 1;
if (nextID > slideCount) 
{
    nextID = 1;
}
$('#slide' + currentID).fadeOut(1000);
$('#slide' + nextID).fadeIn(1000);
currentID = nextID;
```

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LjTXZ/

Comment: Also, try considering using `$('.slides:nth-child(3)')` so your HTML doesn't need to be numbered.

Comment: Ah, never realized it. So its a logical flaw, my bad. Thanks for that.